# CORS doesn't work

Tags: jsonp, cors

i was trying to make asynchronous call to Yahoo's symbol suggest JSONP API, so there's cross domain problem, I have read [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) document and try to change it's url , the following are the codes i use

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
                    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
                    xhr.open(method, url, true);
                } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
                    // XDomainRequest for IE.
                    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xhr.open(method, url);
                } else {
                    // CORS not supported.
                    xhr = null;
                }
                return xhr;
            }


            function makeCorsRequest() {
                // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
      //          var url = 'http://updates.html5rocks.com';

               var url = 'http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=google&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback';
                var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
                if (!xhr) {
                    alert('CORS not supported');
                    return;
                }

                // Response handlers.
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var text = xhr.responseText;
                    console.log(text);
                };

                xhr.onerror = function() {
                    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
                };

                xhr.send();
            }
```

but the problem still not solved:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

does anyone know why? Also, I compared the code in document with regular ajax code, they are almost the same, how does CORS work?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CORS to work, the server needs to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If you do not control the server, and the server hasn't set that header, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

CORS replaces JSONP as the way to load cross-domain json content, but with JSONP the server also needs to implement it.

If the owner of the content doesn't want you to use it, the browser will reject it.

Edit: of course you can avoid the cross-browser issue by having your server get the content from the original server, and having the browser get it from your own server. More work, but it's not cross-browser anymore.

Comment: I've run into the very same problem. It's clearly not immediately obvious what the real idea behind CORS is, but there's a good reason why it works like this. I've added a workaround to my answer, by the way. Feel free to accept my answer if it helps you on your way.